# React performance issues caused by rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an orders component that contains some orders each order has products and the user can update the quantity and price the problem is that the update process is very slow because if I update a product quantity for example all products in the order get remounted again and I think this is the main issue. if I have 100 products the product page render 100 times or more (one time for each product ) here is my current implementation on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-tdd-3nj7g?file=/src/OrderingPage/Order/index.js

here is the order component that have multiple order but for simplicity lets assume we only have one order

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

import Order from "./Order/index";

const OrderingScreen = () => {
  const initialOrderData = {
    order: {
      total: 0,
      vat: 0,
      deliveryCharge: 0,
      date: 0,
      orderStart: 0,
      orderEnd: 0,
      customerGender: "",
      actualPaid: 0,
      dateStr: "",
      payType: "cash",
      itemsCount: 0,
      orderDetails: [
        { name: "prod1", sellPrice: 120, quantity: 3 },
        { name: "prod2", sellPrice: 12, quantity: 2 },
        { name: "prod3", sellPrice: 1123, quantity: 2 },
        { name: "prod4", sellPrice: 1543, quantity: 1 },
        { name: "prod5", sellPrice: 123, quantity: 8 }
      ]
    }
    //other properties
  };

  const [ordersData, setOrdersData] = useState([initialOrderData]);

  const resetOrder = useCallback(() => {
    let ordersDataCopy = [...ordersData];
    ordersDataCopy[0] = initialOrderData;

    setOrdersData(ordersDataCopy);
  }, [ordersData]);

  const updateOrderProducts = useCallback(
    (products) => {
      let ordersCopy = [...ordersData];
      ordersCopy[0]["order"]["orderDetails"] = [...products];
      setOrdersData(ordersCopy);
    },
    [ordersData]
  );

  const updateOrder = useCallback(
    (order) => {
      let ordersCopy = [...ordersData];
      ordersCopy[0]["order"] = { ...order };
      setOrdersData(ordersCopy);
    },
    [ordersData]
  );

  return (
    <Order
      order={ordersData[0].order}
      products={ordersData[0].order.orderDetails}
      updateOrderProducts={updateOrderProducts}
      updateOrder={updateOrder}
      resetOrder={resetOrder}
    />
  );
};

export default OrderingScreen;
```

here is the single order component

```
import OrderItem from "./OrderItem";
import { useEffect, memo, useCallback } from "react";


const Order = ({ order, products, updateOrderProducts, updateOrder }) => {
  const handleOrderChange = useCallback((propertyName, value) => {
    let orderCopy = { ...order };
    orderCopy[propertyName] = value;
    updateOrder(orderCopy);
  });

  const deleteProduct = useCallback((index) => {
    let productsCopy = [...products];
    productsCopy = productsCopy.filter(
      (product) => product !== productsCopy[index]
    );
    updateOrderProducts(productsCopy);
  }, []);

  const handleOrderItemRemove = useCallback((index) => {
    deleteProduct(index);
  }, []);

  const handleQuantityChange = useCallback((index, quantity) => {
    let productsCopy = [...products];

    productsCopy[index]["quantity"] = quantity;

    updateOrderProducts(productsCopy);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="d-flex px-2 flex-grow-1 mb-1">
      {products.map((product, idx) => (
        <OrderItem
          product={product}
          key={idx}
          index={idx}
          onRemove={handleOrderItemRemove}
          onQuantityChange={handleQuantityChange}
          updateProduct={handleOrderChange}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(Order);
```

and the last component which is the product component which I think is causing the performance issue (it render 1 + the number of products in the order if I update the quantity of one product )

```
import RemoveCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/RemoveCircle";
import AddCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircle";

import { memo, useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const OrderItem = ({ product, index, onQuantityChange }) => {
  console.log("remount");

  const [itemQuantity, setItemQuantity] = useState(product.quantity);
  const incrementQuantity = () => {
    onQuantityChange(index, itemQuantity + 1);
  };

  const decrementQuantity = () => {
    itemQuantity > 1 && onQuantityChange(index, itemQuantity - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setItemQuantity(product.quantity);
  }, [product.quantity]);

  const productInfo = useMemo(() => (price, quantity, name) => {
    let total = price * quantity;
    total = +total.toFixed(2);
    price = +price.toFixed(2);
    return (
      <div className={`col-9 col-xl-10  border rounded-start p-1 `}>
        {name}
        <div className="justify-content-around d-flex">
          {"Price:" + price}
          {" Quantity:" + quantity}
          {" Total:" + total}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setItemQuantity(product.quantity);
  }, [product]);

  const quantityColumn = (
    <div>
      <AddCircleIcon onClick={incrementQuantity} />
      {itemQuantity}
      <RemoveCircleIcon onClick={decrementQuantity} />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: "25px" }}>
      {productInfo(product.sellPrice, product.quantity, product.name)}
      {quantityColumn}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(OrderItem);
```

what I want to achieve is a snappy component update (maybe by making the product component mount only for the changed product)

you may see it fast on the sandbox but this version just explains the problem only... the real version is much complicated

Comment: So you've posted a simplified version which may be fast, but the real version is more complicated and slow. How would you expect us to help you there? Have you looked at your browser's dev tools? Have you looked at the React dev tools' profiler?

Comment: the idea remains the same if I posted the real version the things I removed are some UI features that won't affect the performance. the issue is that every product component remounts after changing the quantity or any other property of a single product

Comment: Well, you're creating copies of the order data; what would you expect React to do? Also, is your software actually being slow, or are you just looking at rerenders and thinking it's slow?

Comment: will updating the state using the previous state help? like so :  setOrdersData((prevOrders) => prevOrders.filter(item.id !== id));
and yes the software is actually being slow

Answer (score 0):

You can improve performance by changing your React.memo components.
Instead of memo(OrderItem) pass as second argument function that will compare previous and current state:

```
function areEqualOrderItem(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
  return prevProps.quantity === nextProps.quantity;
}

export default memo(OrderItem, areEqualOrderItem);
```

Also I suggest do not use array index as component key try product name instead of this.

`useCallback` do nothing in your code. Instead you can use this one:

```js
  const handleOrderItemRemove = useCallback((index) => {
    updateOrderProducts(prod => {
        let productsCopy = [...prod];
        productsCopy = productsCopy.filter(
           (product) => product !== productsCopy[index]
        );
        return productsCopy;
    });
  }, [updateOrderProducts]);

  const updateOrderProducts = useCallback(
    (products) => {
      setOrdersData(ords => {
           let ordersCopy = [...ords];
           ords[0]["order"]["orderDetails"] = [...products];
           return ordersCopy;

      });
    },
    [setOrdersData]
  );
```

When you fix all your callbacks you can boost performance. At this time, your code cause rerender of all items almost every small change.